# symbols in restructuredText

Tags: markup, restructuredtext

I want to use some symbols in restructuredText; how can I do this? (e.g. `&rarr;` in Markdown yields the "→" symbol as defined in the [list of standard HTML character entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) -- see also [w3c reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html))

Note: I don't want to require math formula support as a dependency.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have a large number of defined symbols via the "substitution" operator.

You have to include the definitions via `..    include:: <isonum.txt>` or something similar.

Most of them have the form `|larr|` or `|rarr|`.

They are defined in the `docutils.parsers.rst.include` installation directory.   There are dozens of  files which define numerous Unicode characters.

Comment: Hmmm. These look really lousy compared to the Markdown symbols that result.

Comment: "lousy"?  What does that mean in this context?  Are you saying that `&larr;` is worse than `|larr|` or are you saying that your browser font looks lousy?

Comment: I'm looking at this `&rarr;` on this site, and comparing it against Sphinx (using RST) HTML output of |rarr|. Both are HTML and are using the same default font. I'm not sure if they are the same unicode character, I don't have a character-codepoint-decoder on hand.

Comment: You don't need much of a code-point decoder.  The standard HTML entities give you the Unicode character number.  The `<isonum.txt>` file gives you the character defined by RST.  You can create your own definition if the HTML entity is different than the RST entity.

Comment: Hmm. Both sources claim codepoint 0x2192 for rarr, and the surrounding text is in the same font, yet the symbols look different. Something is fishy, and like I said, I don't have a character codepoint decoder.

Comment: Argh -- a red herring, it has something to do with the CSS or font displays, nothing to do with UTF-8 encoding vs. HTML entity encoding. Thanks!

Comment: As a reference: [reStructuredText Standard Definition Files](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/definitions.html).

Answer (score 5):

It was my impression that rst supported Unicode; can you just type in the raw character and let `docutils` handle encoding for HTML?

Comment: hmm... I guess I could, but I'd rather stick to ASCII.

Answer (score 4):

I think you were looking for this: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#raw

You can define the following role:

```
.. role::  raw-html(raw)
    :format: html
```

And then you can write:

```
This way :raw-html:`&rarr;`
```

Which renders like this:

This way →

Comment: thanks but that only works with HTML; restructuredText has various backends other than HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when making html from .rst files containing the ± character in Windows using Sphinx.  Changing the file encoding from windows-1252 to UTF-8 fixed it for me.

Simply open with notepad, Save As..., and change Encoding: to UTF-8